# Beautiful Soup Looping elements and get the text of current element only if there is any and their parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am learning BeautifulSoup and have a webpage that has a body something like this:

html:

```
<div>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>
     this is div text
     <a name='abc'>this is anchor text</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
tag     text                   parents
===     =====                  =======
div     ""                     ""
table   ""                     div
...
div       this is div text     div.table.tr.td
a         this is anchor text  div.table.tr.td.a
```

I am able to get the result but the problem is in div I am getting the anchor text also which is as below

```
div       this is div text this is anchor text     div.table.tr.td
a         this is anchor text                      div.table.tr.td.a
```

Below is my code

```
f = open("C:/abc.html",encoding="utf8")  
soup=BeautifulSoup(f,"lxml")
f.close()
for tag in soup.find_all():
      allparent=""
      for parenttags in tag.findParents():
          allparent=parenttags.name+"."+allparent
      if allparent!="":
          allparent=allparent[:-1]
      print(tag.name+"', '"+tag.text+"','"+allparent)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am trying to get all tag with it's own text and all parent tags. Further I will group by the data on the parents to get the average count of words in same kind of tags and other calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **`tag.find(text=True)`**

If `tag` is your `<div>foo<span>bar</span></div>`:

- `tag.find(text=True)` will output `foo`
- `tag.text` will output `foo bar`.

So, in your case, just replace

```
print(tag.name+"', '"+tag.text+"','"+allparent)`
```

by

```
print(tag.name+"', '"+tag.find(text=True)+"','"+allparent)
```

---

Or better,

```
print('"{}", "{}", "{}"'.format(tag.name, tag.find(text=True), allparent))
```

Isn't that sexier?!